# InputAccessoryView not removed

Tags: xcode, keyboard, inputaccessoryview, swift4.2

I'm making an iOS app, in which i use the `inputaccessoryview` to the `UIViewController`,

the problem is

**Controller A**

```
   class  ControllerA: UIViewController { 

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return saveView
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func openVCB(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let controllerB = controllerB.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .main)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controllerB)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Controller B**

```
   class  ControllerB: UIViewController { 

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

in the `controller A` the view is working as expected, but in `controller B` if i opened a keyboard and closed it the `AccossoryView` it will be visible, and it supposed not to be visible, any ideas?

Full Project  [InpoutViewTest](https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/InpoutViewTest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this approach:

```
var shouldBecomeFirstResponder:Bool = false

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
return shouldBecomeFirstResponder
}
```

and don't forget to set this flag to false in `viewWillDisappear` as well

```
 shouldBecomeFirstResponder = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem too. Try putting this in your `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` function:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   if let myInputAccessoryView = saveView {
      myInputAccessoryView.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

It should remove the input accessory view before transitioning to `controller B`. Just remember to add the input accessory view back when returning to `controller A`. You could also try `myInputAccessoryView.isHidden = true` instead of `removeFromSuperview()` if you prefer.

Comment: I try it but still same issue